# The ViewData item that has the key 'Mission.Id' is of type 'System.Guid' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-7.0

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Mission = new SelectList(_context.DefinedMissionContext, "Id", "Name");
            ViewBag.Qr = new SelectList(_context.QRContext, "Id", "Name");
            return View(new DefinedMissionPath());
        }
```

CSHTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Mission.Id" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Mission.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Mission, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
                <span asp-validation-for="Mission.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Qr.Id" class="control-label"></label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Qr.Id, (SelectList)ViewBag.Qr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
                <span asp-validation-for="Qr.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

ID of all models is in Guid type

Error Code :
`InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 'Mission.Id' is of type 'System.Guid' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.`

I updated my model and other parts to the following model direction, but the same problem continues.

```
public class DefinedMissionPath
{
    // ...
    public Guid MissionId { get; set; }
    public virtual DefinedMission Mission { get; set; }
    public Guid QrId { get; set; }
    public virtual QR Qr { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved;

I added a string type item to my model that will not be included in migration operations.

```
public class DefinedMissionPath : Base
{


    public DefinedMission? Mission { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long Order { get; set; }
    public QR? Qr { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Directions Directions { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Required]
    public string? MissionItem { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    [Required]
    public string? QrItem { get; set; }

}
```

I later updated my cs html code for this.

```
 <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="MissionItem" class="control-label"></label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MissionItem, (SelectList)ViewBag.Mission, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
            <span asp-validation-for="MissionItem" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="QrItem" class="control-label"></label>
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.QrItem, (SelectList)ViewBag.Qr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control"})
            <span asp-validation-for="QrItem" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

Finally, I made an addition to find the object from the incoming id in the create in post method.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(DefinedMissionPath definedMissionPath)
    {
        definedMissionPath.Qr = _context.QRContext.Find(Guid.Parse(definedMissionPath.QrItem ?? string.Empty));
        definedMissionPath.Mission = _context.DefinedMissionContext.Find(Guid.Parse(definedMissionPath.MissionItem ?? string.Empty));
        
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            definedMissionPath.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            definedMissionPath.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
            _context.Add(definedMissionPath);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewBag.Mission = new SelectList(_context.DefinedMissionContext, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.Qr = new SelectList(_context.QRContext, "Id", "Name");
        return View(definedMissionPath);
    }
```

The get method of creation still hasn't changed as I threw above.